# Printing 2D Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm trying print a 10x10 grid, I don't need any particular symbols, just the 10x10 format.  There's actually a lot more to the whole program but right now I'm stuck on this.  I really just want to print *'s for a simple Pacman game.  I'm not good at programming at all, but I have to pass so I can graduate next semester.  Here is what I have so far;

```
public class Pacman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int columns = 0;
        int rows = 0;

        int[][] grid = new int[rows][columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++){
            System.out.println(grid[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

I don't have errors in syntax or compiling, but nothing actually prints.

Comment: You have created array with 0 rows and 0 columns. What exactly you expect to be printed?

Comment: That's the thing, I have no idea what I'm doing.  It took me 2 hours just to write what I have now.

Comment: I second @akhil_mittal and I will also point out that you probably want to use `System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");` instead of `println` so that it doesn't move to the next line (it appears that you are trying to print 10 across and 10 down).

Comment: Ok, I removed "ln" from the print and initialized the rows and columns to 10, and now everything is in one single line that looks like this;

Comment: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 [[I@1896d2c20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: @Jerrod If you don't know what are you doing then how can anyone help you?

Comment: @akhil_mittal That's why I'm here.  To ask for help from people who do know what they are doing.  If you can't understand that I'm a beginner in programming and all I'm looking for is guidance in figuring something out and that my professors have no interest in trying to help me, than I would appreciate you moving on.  I need help.  I'm not asking anyone to write my program for me.  When I troubleshoot and try numerous different variations and nothing works, I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int columns = 10;
int rows = 10;

int[][] grid = new int[rows][columns];



for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++)
    {
        grid[i][j] = 0;
        System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

That will print out a 10x10 with every number in the array being 0

Comment: @Jerrod Yeah no problem. Please do post back here if you have any more questions

Comment: This will certainly not be my last time asking a question, I assure you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int columns = 10;
        int rows = 10;

        int[][] grid = new int[rows][columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++){
            System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

}
```